# How can i play local video files in videogular2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, videogular

i am using videogular2 for playing video files. Playing streaming videos was done successfully and i want to play local video file as well. This is my code..

```
<vg-player>
      <vg-buffering></vg-buffering>
      <vg-scrub-bar [vgSlider]="true" style="display: none;">
      </vg-scrub-bar>
      <video [vgMedia]="media" #media id="singleVideo" preload="auto" controls>
        <source src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Kurnool%20Achars%20Chintana/telugu/adhyatma_rasaranjani_telugu_hyderabad_/VID-20180817-WA0002.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  </vg-player>
```

And this was not playing local videos. How can i play local video in videogular2

Comment: If you're using WKWebView on iOS, your file path needs to be rewritten to `/storage/emulated/0/Kurnool%20Achars%20Chintana/telugu/adhyatma_rasaranjani_telugu_hyderabad_/VID-20180817-WA0002.mp4`(the same without the `file://` at the beginning). See the CORS section here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/

Comment: @ravi, have you found the solution?